# d3v4 inverse bubble chart with animation/screen size adaptation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am trying to convert a bubble chart from d3v3 to v4. Running into x,y,d missing variables?

In this version -- a rect is applied to the svg - and then a circle is cut -- so its like an inverse bubble chart.

I am keen to work out a set radius for the chart as a maxium -- if it should act like a score between 0 and 100? What kind of math to apply that a max radius has been reached to signify that the value is very big?

I also tried to have the svg mask adapt - if the browser or its container changed size -- ideally would want it to response during the change - rather than resizeEnd

//version 3
https://jsfiddle.net/8ag1vf6e/1/

//current version 4
https://jsfiddle.net/d56g9r0y/

```
    // filters go in defs element
    var defs = innversebubble.append("defs");

    var mask = defs.append("mask")
      .attr("id", "myMask");

    mask.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("opacity", 1);

    var invisiblebubble = mask.append("circle")
      .data(data);

    //create a fixed bubble first                  
    invisiblebubble
      .attr("cx", "50%")
      .attr("cy", "50%")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.value - 20;
      });

    //now mask the fixed circle     
    var masker = defs.append(function() {
        return mask.node().cloneNode(true)
      })
      .attr("id", "myMaskForPointer")
      .select("rect")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("opacity", 1);

    invisiblebubble
      .attr("r", 10);

    //apply the rest of the chart elements 

    var rect = innversebubble
      .attr("class", "series")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("mask", "url(#myMask)")
      .style("fill", backcolor)
      .style("opacity", backopacity);


    //animate this circle

    invisiblebubble
      .attr("cx", "50%")
      .attr("cy", "50%")
      .transition()
      .duration(1800)
      .attr("r", 10)
      .transition()
      .duration(900)
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });
```

latest jsfiddle - 15th June -- needs fixing
https://jsfiddle.net/xmrtahns/

"I am keen to work out a set radius for the chart as a maxium -- if it should act like a score between 0 and 100? What kind of math to apply that a max radius has been reached to signify that the value is very big?

I also tried to have the svg mask adapt - if the browser or its container changed size -- ideally would want it to response during the change - rather than resizeEnd"

Comment: Running into x,y,d missing variables in this conversion from v3 to v4

Comment: Unable to resolve these variables - x, y, d https://jsfiddle.net/d56g9r0y/

Comment: managed to get it functional again - but needs a major clearup with the primary data source and the rest of the variables - https://jsfiddle.net/xmrtahns/ I am keen to work out a set radius for the chart as a maxium -- if it should act like a score between 0 and 100? What kind of math to apply that a max radius has been reached to signify that the value is very big?

I also tried to have the svg mask adapt - if the browser or its container changed size -- ideally would want it to response during the change - rather than resizeEnd

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the conversion and the data source - but still need issues to resolve.

```
    var backcolor = $this.data("color");
    var backopacity = $this.data("opacity");

    var width = $this.data("width");
    var height = $this.data("height");

    var data = [{
      "label": $this.data("label-name"),
      "centralLabel": $this.data("central-label"),
      "xPer": $this.data("displace-left"),
      "yPer": $this.data("displace-top"),
      "value": $this.data("bubble-value")
    }];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLymw8et/2/

--I am keen to work out a set radius for the chart as a maximum -- if it should act like a score between 0 and 100? 
--What kind of math to apply that a max radius has been reached to signify that the value is very big? 
--I also tried to have the svg mask adapt - if the browser or its container changed size -- ideally would want it to response during the change - rather than resizeEnd –

Comment: latest - with showing pointers - http://jsfiddle.net/hLymw8et/2/